# Гео-объект, как скрыть / отобразить и эмулировать клик по гео-объекту зная его id?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

На карте создаются геообъекты. У этих объектов есть уникальный для каждого id и при клике открывается попап с информацией о гообъекте (http://clip2net.com/s/3PWEiom). Пожалуйста, скажите, как можно скрыть, сделать видимым снова и эмулировать клик по этому геообъекту зная его id (например, id="place-1").
Вот код создания объектов на карте

```
(function ($) {
"use strict";

ymaps.ready(init);

var data = [];

var $mapBlock = $('.js-map');

function init() {
    var defaultCoords = [55.76, 37.64];
    var userCoords = defaultCoords;
    //Список городов
    var citys = {};
    $('.js-dealers-cities').each(function() {
        var city = $(this).data('city-name');
        var lat = $(this).data('city-lat');
        var lng = $(this).data('city-lng');
        citys[city] = {};
        citys[city]['lat'] = lat;
        citys[city]['lng'] = lng;
    });

    var geolocation = ymaps.geolocation,
        myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: defaultCoords,
            zoom: 12,
            controls: []
        }),

        objectManager = new ymaps.ObjectManager({
            // Чтобы метки начали кластеризоваться, выставляем опцию.
            clusterize: false,
            geoObjectOpenBalloonOnClick: true,
            clusterOpenBalloonOnClick: false
        });

    myMap.controls.add('zoomControl', {
        position: {
            right: 10,
            bottom: 110
        }
    });

    geolocation.get({
        provider: 'yandex',
        mapStateAutoApply: false //true - автоматом центровать по положению пользователя
    }).then(function (result) {
        //Координаты пользователя
        userCoords = result.geoObjects.position;
```

myMap.setCenter(userCoords, 6, {
                        flying: true,
                        duration: 0
                    });
            }
        });

```
    myMap.geoObjects.add(objectManager);

    $mapBlock.find('.map-point').each(function () {
        var $that = $(this);
        var coords = $(this).data('coords').split(',');

        if (!Layout.isDesktopLayout()) {
            data.push({
                "type": "Feature",
                "id": $that.data('id'),
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": coords
                }
            });
        } else {
            data.push({
                "type": "Feature",
                "id": $that.data('id'),
                "geometry": {
                    "type": "Point",
                    "coordinates": coords
                },
                "properties": {
                    "balloonContent": $that.html()
                }
            });
        }
    });

    objectManager.add(data);

    function onObjectEvent(id) {
        console.log(id);

        objectManager.objects.setObjectOptions(id, {
            balloonOffset: [-105, -35],
            hideIconOnBalloonOpen: false,
            balloonAutoPanMargin: 5,
            iconLayout: 'default#image',
            iconImageHref: '/themes/frontend/html/static/images/map-point.svg',
            iconImageSize: [25, 38],
            iconContentOffset: [-12, -19]
        });
    }

    function openPopup(e) {
        if (!Layout.isDesktopLayout()) {
            Popups.openById(e.get('objectId'));
        }
    }

    $mapBlock.find('.map-point').each(function () {
        objectManager.objects.events.fire('click', onObjectEvent($(this).data('id')));
    });

    objectManager.objects.events.add('click', openPopup);

}
```

})(jQuery);

Answer (score 1):

Доброе утро.

К сожалению, ObjectManager не учитывает опцию "visible" у объекта. Так что единственный способ скрыть объект с карты в OM - это удалить его из менеджера.

Эмулировать событие в теории можно. Если взять координаты геообъекта через метод getById и вызвать objectManager.objects.events.fire('click', ... с этими данными.
Но если задача состоит в том, чтобы вызывать открытие попапа программно, то архитектурно правильней будет это делать не через обработчик нативного события. Но тут уж надо задачу понять.